# Taking string as input but dealing with characters individually in C++

Tags: c++, string

I wanted to know if there is any efficient method of getting a string as input and then performing some operation on its characters individually?

Also, after performing operations (check that length of string may also increase or decrease), can we output the new string (string got after performing operations) instead of outputting the characters individually using a for loop?

Note that time is a crucial factor, please provide fastest methods.

Comment: What is your attempt so far?

Comment: I took a string as input using getline, found its length and then looped through its characters but then when I have to output the new string, it is to be done character-wise plus the method is not fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is any efficient method of getting a string as input and then performing some operation on its characters individually?

Yes, there is: read `std::string` as usual (say, with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or the `>>` operator of an input stream), and then access the individual characters in a loop.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
for (int i = 0 ; i != str.size() ; i++) {
    std::cout << "Code of character " << i << " is " << (int)str[i] << std::endl;
}
```

[First demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/kryzjR)

> Also, after performing operations, can we output the new string (string got after performing operations) instead of outputting the characters individually using a for loop?

Yes, you can: `std::string` is *mutable*, meaning that you can change it in place.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
for (int i = 0 ; i != str.size() ; i++) {
    if (!std::isalpha(str[i])) {
        str[i] = '#';
    }
}
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

[Second demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/eDA0iW)

Comment: I did this much thing but is there a way to do this more efficiently? And can I output the new string using write() function?

Comment: Why aren't you using std::string::iterator?

Comment: Its c++, use "std::cout << yourString << std::endl;" to print

Comment: @Mayerz I would definitely use it in production code, but I am not sure if the OP has advanced to studying iterators in his learning of C++, so I decided to stay on the safe side.

Comment: @timidgeek This pretty much is as efficient as it gets - there's little opportunity to getting inefficient with accessing string elements.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Better get used to good practices, but you are probably right

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string in;
  cout << "Input please\n";
  cin >> in;
  if(in.size() >= 5)
    in[5] = 'A';
  cout << in << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Or you can use `std::getline()`, instead of `std::cin`.

Output:

```
Input please
samaras
samarAs
```

However, are you sure this is the bottleneck of your program? You can check this with some profiling tools, like the [one](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/profiling-tools/) I use.

[EDIT]

Since OP is asking about efficiency, I did some testing. However, you can to take into account the time that user takes to type the input, but since I am the same person, we can assume this is constant.

So, I did modified a bit a code from another answer, like this:

```
  std::string str;
  cout << "Input please\n";
  std::getline(std::cin, str);
  if (str.size() >= 5) {
    str[5] = '#';
  }

  std::cout << str << "\n";
```

Output:

```
Input please
Samaras
Samar#s
It took me 1.04237 seconds.
```

And with my code, I got

```
Input please
Samaras
SamarAs
It took me 0.911217 seconds.
```

Which actually show that they are pretty close and I would say the difference is due to my typing speed.

I did the timings with `std::chrono`, like the [code](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/) I have in my pseudo-site.

Comment: Someone asking this question doesn't need profiling tools imho.

Comment: When you want to make your code more efficient, you should try to optimize the bottleneck of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Basic operation... Some search on the internet could have helped you but here you go...

```
std::string processStr(const std::string &str) 
{
  for (std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    // process your string (getting a char is done by dereferencing the iterator
    //  like this: *it
  return (str);
}
```

Comment: How do I output the string?
Also, consider that the length of string may vary.

Comment: This solution adapt to any length.

you can output the returned str like this:


std::cout << processStr("blabla") << std::endl;